# Why my React app runs firebase query in useEffect when I alter the database?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My code is supposed to load data on the first render so I fetched the documents from firebase in useEffect and stored them in the state "data". It works fine, all the documents are displayed on the page as I wanted. Now I wanted to delete individual documents on clicking a button under each of them. I did so with the help of a deleteDoc function which deletes the document from the database (and a file from storage if it exists). The deletion works fine but after the delete is successful, my code reloads the data from the database again for some reason causing the app to rerender the page again. I console logged at 2 different places in useEffect and found that useEffect doesn't execute the whole code inside it but only the part where it fetches the data from firebase. I just want it to perform that operation in the background and not interfere with the data state again. So how can I stop this re fetching every time I delete a document?

```
 const [data, setData] = useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      user.getIdTokenResult().then((idTokenResult) => {
        setAdmin(idTokenResult.claims.admin);
      });

      db.collection("files")
        .orderBy("timeStamp", "desc")
        .limit(5)
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
          console.log(data, "In query"); // This executes after the delete operation
          setData(
            snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
              return [doc.data(), { doc_id: doc.ref.id }];
            })
          );
        });
    }

    console.log(data, "Outside query"); // This doesn't execute after the delete operation
   }, []);
```

Delete function:

```
 const deleteDoc = async (e, item) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Deleting file from storage if it exists
    if (item[0].file_name) {
      const deleteTask = storage
        .ref("users/" + user.uid)
        .child(item[0].file_name);

      deleteTask
        .delete()
        .then(() => {
          console.log("File deleted Successfully");
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
     
    // Deleting document from firestore collection.
    db.collection("files")
      .doc(item[1].doc_id)
      .delete()
      .then(() => {
        setData(
          data.filter((doc) => {
            return doc[1].doc_id !== item[1].doc_id;
          })
        );
        console.log("Document successfully deleted!", data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling `onSnapshot` to get the data from Firestore, you're attaching a permanent listener that [listens for realtime updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen). So it is indeed expected that your callback gets called again (and thus the state updated again) when the database changes.

If you only want to [get the data once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data), use `get()` instead of `onSnapshot()`:

```
db.collection("files")
  .orderBy("timeStamp", "desc")
  .limit(5)
  .get().then((snapshot) => {
    ...
```

Comment: Hey man thank you so much! It worked. I had no idea about permanent listeners. Just one thing to note: get() returns a promise so I had to use ".get().then((snapshot) => { ... })" and it worked.

Comment: Done both of them! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

According this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) we can listen to changes in collection using `onSnapshot` So when you delete document in db, `onSnapshot` will listen to new change and will execute logic inside that function.

Solution to this is to **Detach a listener**

```
const unsubscribe = db.collection("files")
    .orderBy("timeStamp", "desc")
    .limit(5)
    .onSnapshot(() => {
      // Respond to data
      // ...
    });

// Later ...

// Stop listening to changes
unsubscribe();
```

Second solution is to use another state let's say `fetchData` and once you receive data on load set it to `false` like below:-

```
 const [data, setData] = useState([]);
 const [fetchData, setFetchData] = useState(true);

 useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      user.getIdTokenResult().then((idTokenResult) => {
        setAdmin(idTokenResult.claims.admin);
      });

      db.collection("files")
        .orderBy("timeStamp", "desc")
        .limit(5)
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
          if(fetchData) {
            setData(
              snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
                return [doc.data(), { doc_id: doc.ref.id }];
              })
            );
            setFetchData(false);
          }
        });
     }
   }, []);
```

Comment: Hey! thanks for the answer. I tried both methods, however they did not work. I think for some reason the states are also getting refreshed so fetchData gets set to true again after I have deleted a document. And when I log the data in the onSnapshot method, it shows an empty array. It's hurting my brain thinking what's going on here..!